# Are animals straying onto the runway considered to be a runway incursion?

Tags: runways, runway-incursion

Are animals on the runway defined as a runway incursion?

Comment: Not if they were cleared to cross by ATC.

Comment: No comment for the previous post.

Comment: I have to link to this story: http://aviationhumor.net/deer-on-the-runway/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [FAA defines a runway incursion](https://www.faa.gov/airports/runway_safety/news/runway_incursions/) as:

> Any occurrence at an aerodrome involving the incorrect presence of an **aircraft, vehicle or person** on the protected area of a surface designated for the landing and take off of aircraft.

So **no**.

Comment: This is the ICAO definition as well

Answer (score 4):

They are considered a runway obstruction not incursion.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this? Is it valid worldwide or in your country?

Comment: I've always heard 'obstruction' in reference to inanimate objects on the runway -- storm debris, blown tire remnants, etc.  Wildlife hazard is the the term I've heard most commonly used to warn of critters on the runway.  Here in Florida, tortoises and alligators routinely wander onto runways.  The tower usually redirects traffic to avoid them until they wander off.

Comment: Perfect answer, master!

Comment: @eduardoguilherme The reason this is not a perfect answer is that you don't know if it is true or not.

Comment: While in Alaska, other creatures are obstructions...http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/north/seal-runway-alaska-airport-1.4372369

Comment: It's true, at least in the United States. I have worked operations for many years.

Comment: @mins, why does the distinction matter?  An animal on the runway has the same effect on an airplane hitting it worldwide, regardless of how we label it...

Comment: Well, in my opinion it is a runway obstruction, not a runway incursion.

Answer (score 0):

No but they are a FOD hazard!

Reminds me of a funny ATC conversation I heard out at KRVS a long time ago:

Tower: Cessna Niner Fife Four Fife Niner clear for takeoff Runway one niner right.

Cessna 95459: Unable to comply…there appears to be a skunk on the active.

Tower: …well if I had a .22 I’d grease him for you, but continue holding short and let me know when he’s clear of the active.