# What measures are there at Vancouver International Airport to prevent wild animals from entering the airport?

Tags: safety, airport

This video shows a wild coyote on a taxiway at Vancouver International Airport (CYVR):

I ask from the standpoint of safety, and menace to aircraft. Does CYVR lack adequate animal control against [runway obstructions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/45088)? What measures are there to prevent such incidents in the future?

Comment: I tried to make the post on-topic. I think this is what you wanted to ask about. If not, please feel free to edit again...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that coyotes may not be as big an issue as you might think:

> Coyotes are a particular problem for the airport. Formerly, this was
> addressed by chasing them around the aerodrome in an attempt to herd
> them through the gates. Now, following our review, the coyotes are now
> tolerated airside and ‘trained’ to avoid runways, with the added
> benefit that they now contribute to mitigating the strike risk by
> preying on the bird population.

That's [from the website of a company](https://avisure.com/wp/yvr-wildlife-management/) that consulted with YVR on their [wildlife management program](https://www.yvr.ca/en/about-yvr/environment/wildlife-management-program).

Given the sheer size of a large airport it's unrealistic to expect an 'airtight' perimeter. An animal could run in while a gate is opened, and [coyotes can swim](https://northamericannature.com/can-coyotes-swim/) so water isn't an obstacle.